# Hide leanModal div with form

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

First of all I want to say I am not a javascript expert at all..

I am testing [Ray Stone](https://twitter.com/finelysliced)'s [leanModal pluggin](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/).
I am able to open and close modal using the pluggin.

I have added a form to modal div.
What I want to do now is to close the modal when user clicks submit button (as you can see in project website).

The problem is that I don't process the form as usual. I get the data using jQuery and I do request to server using `$.ajax()`. Here is my code:

```
 $(function() {
     $('#add-user').submit(function() {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: '***',
             data: '***',
             contentType: 'application/json',
             dataType: 'json'
         });
         $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
         $(this).leanModal.closeModal('#cp');
         return false;
     }); 
});
```

Where
 `#add-user` is the link that opens the modal.
 `#cp` is the div id of the modal.

In this case the div gets close but the blur behind the div does not dissapear until user do clicks. The effect is the same than using `$('#cp').remove();`
How can I totally close the div when the request is sent?
Thanks in advance

**Update:** A jsFiddle with my code is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PTGFQ/).
Some CSS rules are missed and I have not featured the AJAX request but I think the main code is there.

Comment: Can you please try to give a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with you example ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY jsFiddle is added.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `$.ajax()` is asynchronous so the following lines

```
$(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
$(this).leanModal.closeModal('#cp');
```

will be executed even if your query is not successful.
You would better do

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function () {
        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
        $(this).leanModal.closeModal('#cp');
    }
});
```

Secondly, after [checking the source](https://github.com/FinelySliced/leanModal.js/blob/master/jquery.leanModal.js#L62), I think you should use

```
$.leanModal.close_modal('#cp');
```

`$("#lean_overlay")` seems to be the "blur" element you want to get rid of.
Ultimately you could do `$("#lean_overlay").remove()` but the plugin seems to manage it already

Finally you should have

```
$(function() {
    $('#add-user').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '***',
            data: '***',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () {
                $('#add-user :input:not(:submit)').val('');
                $.leanModal.close_modal('#add-user');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I've tried. The server response is 200 OK. But the div is still there. Am I missing something? Which is the success condition?

Comment: Ok so you don't have to observe the event in your add-user button but in your form submission

Comment: I am sorry. `#add-user`  is the form id. This was my mistake. I will try to create one jsFiddle with the logic inside the page related to the problem.